# count.index for dictionary in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, indexing

Is it possible to auto generate the vm10,vm11,vm12 in the below script (as count.index used in terraform) ? I would like to pass/define name "vm" and should be able to deploy 3 vm's with the different names vm10, vm11 and vm12. Please suggest a way, Thanks

```yaml
---
- hosts: Target                         
  vars:
    machines:                  
      v10:
        mem: 1024
        vcpu: 1
      v11:
        mem: 1024
        vcpu: 1
  tasks:
  - name: img cpy
    copy:
      src: /root/pri.qcow2
      dest: /test/{{ item.key }}.qcow2
      remote_src: yes
    with_dict: "{{ machines }}"
  - name: Import/Load VM
    command: >
             virt-install --name {{ item.key }} --memory {{ item.value.mem }} --vcpus {{ item.value.vcpu }} --disk /test/{{ item.key }}.qcow2,bus=sata --import --os-variant generic --network default --noreboot
    with_dict: "{{ machines }}"
```

Comment: note: `with_dict` is deprecated. [Use `loop` instead](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider: according to https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html with_* is not deprecated ("We have not deprecated the use of with_<lookup> - that syntax will still be valid for the foreseeable future.")

Answer (score 1):

Use an inventory instead of a dict. You want 100 vms?

```yaml
vms:
  hosts:
    vm[001:100]:
      mem: 1024
      vcpu: 1
```

This will be interpreted as `vm001`,`vm002`,...,`vm099`,`vm100`.
[Delegate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html) the task to create them to localhost, since they don't exist when the task is run. Afterwards you can run the [setup module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html) and run tasks directly on the newly created VMs.

The corresponding playbook would look like this:

```yaml
---
- hosts: vms
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: copy qcow image to target path
    copy:
      src: /root/ovms/pri.qcow2
      dest: /root/ovms/test/{{ inventory_hostname }}.qcow2
      remote_src: yes
    delegate_to: target
  - name: Import/Load VM
    command: >
            virt-install --name {{ inventory_hostname }} --memory {{ mem }} --vcpus {{ vcpu }} --disk /root/ovms/test/{{ inventory_hostname }}.qcow2,bus=sata --import --os-variant generic --network default --noreboot
    delegate_to: target
```

Comment: Hi @GeraldSchneider, Thanks for the update ! But my query is that, Now its just vm10, vm11 and vm12 (3 vm's) mentioning them in vars with dict is easier. But incase if I wanted to deploy 100vm's, should I still mention 100 vmname's ? or can we do something for that ? (As in terraform, [link](https://emilwypych.com/2017/10/15/deploying-multiple-vsphere-vms-terraform/?cn-reloaded=1) there is something like count.index+1)

Comment: If you need to specify a different configuration for every VM there is not much you can do to automate this. Of course it would be easy to just number them when they all have the same configuration.

Comment: Yes they have same config and same qcow2 image being used for all 100+ vm's

Comment: In your example the configuration varies (different memory)

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake from my end. I mentioned diff mem. But all the vms are going to be same config

Comment: I modified my answer with a different solution that seems more fitting.

Comment: I have edited the ansible task in the question section. Will inventory help me on this case ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it for that. Delegate the tasks to the target machine.

Comment: Thanks alot Gerald, with inventory it works !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128455/discussion-between-shiva-ranjini-and-gerald-schneider).

Comment: Hi Gerald, Ansible playbook does not show any progress after executing the task. I have to manually press ctrl + C to exit. This happens only when I load vm's in running state. If vm's loaded in off state, it shows the progress.                                           
 TASK [copy qcow image to target path] ***************************************************************
changed: [vm-1 -> x.x.x.x]
changed: [vm-2 -> x.x.x.x]

TASK [Import/Load VM] *********************************************************************************************************
[ERROR]: User interrupted execution

Comment: Please ask a new question for that. Include verbose output. Check on the target host for hanging processes.